# How to connect opengl_glad 4.6 and glfw to Lazarus free pascal?

Tags: opengl, glfw, freepascal, lazarus

I completely redid the code from the last question.It works, but with the standard opengl lazarus and with the glfw library, when glad_gl 4.6 is connected, it issues an external access violation error with the message access violation executing address $000000000000000000

[Attempt to connect glad to free pascal opengl 4 6 Error at startup Wrong number of parameters specified for call to gladLoadGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193583/attempt-to-connect-glad-to-free-pascal-opengl-4-6-error-at-startup-wrong-number)

glfw.pas was taken from github https://github.com/Blueicaro/GLFW/blob/master/Glfw33/glfw.pas

```
program project1;


uses
gl, glad_gl, glfw;

var
  window: PGLFWwindow;

begin
  if glfwInit() = 0 then
  ExitCode := -1;

  window := glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, 'Hello World', nil, nil);
  if window = nil then
  begin
    glfwTerminate();
    ExitCode := -1;
  end;

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  while glfwWindowShouldClose(window) = 0 do
  begin
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

                      glColor3d(1,0,0);


 glVertex2f(-1, -1);
 glColor3d(1,1,0);
 glVertex2f(1, -1);
 glColor3d(1,0,1);
 glVertex2f(0, 1);

 glEnd;
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    glfwPollEvents();
  end;

  glfwTerminate();
   ExitCode := 0;
end.
```

connect opengl glad 4.6

Comment: *access violation executing address $000000000000000000* always means that you are accessing an OpenGL method that hasn't been loaded. Probably you are not initializing glad. Something like `gladInit()` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(...)`.

Comment: The code in your comment still doesn't contain a call to `gladInit()`.

Comment: if gladInit() = 0 then
    begin
  ExitCode := -1;

    end; outputs an error project1.lpr(13,6) Error: Identifier not found "gladInit"